# How to dynamically add meta tag using XSLT

Tags: html, xml, xslt, meta

I have a specific problem where I have to add a meta tag to a HTML using XSLT.

What I need to do is to keep the body and add a meta tag with the content of the tag 'option'.

The code that I want is something like that, or something that do what this was supposed to do:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="option" content="   <xsl:value-of select="//option" />   " />
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:value-of select="html/body" />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

You can see that the content of the meta tag is also a value that I want to get from the document.

For example, if I use the following code, it works fine:

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta name="option" content="Test" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:value-of select="html/body" />
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

However, the content will be fixed as "Test".

There is any way to add a dynamic meta tag using just XSLT?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`Attribute Value Template`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xslt-30-20170608/#attribute-value-templates) wrapping the XPath expression in  `{` and `}` like

```
<meta name="option" content="{//option}" />
```